# How to make a 2-axis bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm attempting to visually compare the counts of 2 species on a single plot, for multiple years in R. I saw this plot online and am hoping to create something similar in R, but haven't found much online that helps.

[image]

My data:

```
> head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Zone, Year [6]
   Year Zone      weighted_den weighted_den_carid
  <dbl> <fct>            <dbl>              <dbl>
1  2009 West           0.00109           0.485   
2  2009 Rankin         0                 0.0869  
3  2009 Whipray        0                 0.000176
4  2009 Crocodile      0                 0.0213  
5  2010 West           0.00245           2.26    
6  2010 Rankin         0                 0
```

My attempt:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Zone)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=weighted_den_carid), col = 'red') +
  geom_bar(aes(y=weighted_den), col = 'blue') +
  scale_y_continuous("Carid", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *100, name = "Cneb")) +
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

dput format of my data:

> dput(df)
> structure(list(Year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009,
> 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011,
> 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012,
> 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013,
> 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015,
> 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016,
> 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018,
> 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
> 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020,
> 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), Zone = structure(c(3L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Crocodile", "Rankin",
> "West", "Whipray"), class = "factor"), code = c("2009-West",
> "2009-West", "2009-Rankin", "2009-Rankin", "2009-Whipray", "2009-Whipray",
> "2009-Crocodile", "2009-Crocodile", "2010-West", "2010-West",
> "2010-Rankin", "2010-Rankin", "2010-Whipray", "2010-Whipray",
> "2010-Crocodile", "2010-Crocodile", "2011-West", "2011-West",
> "2011-Rankin", "2011-Rankin", "2011-Whipray", "2011-Whipray",
> "2011-Crocodile", "2011-Crocodile", "2012-West", "2012-West",
> "2012-Rankin", "2012-Rankin", "2012-Whipray", "2012-Whipray",
> "2012-Crocodile", "2012-Crocodile", "2013-West", "2013-West",
> "2013-Rankin", "2013-Rankin", "2013-Whipray", "2013-Whipray",
> "2013-Crocodile", "2013-Crocodile", "2014-West", "2014-West",
> "2014-Rankin", "2014-Rankin", "2014-Whipray", "2014-Whipray",
> "2014-Crocodile", "2014-Crocodile", "2015-West", "2015-West",
> "2015-Rankin", "2015-Rankin", "2015-Whipray", "2015-Whipray",
> "2015-Crocodile", "2015-Crocodile", "2016-West", "2016-West",
> "2016-Rankin", "2016-Rankin", "2016-Whipray", "2016-Whipray",
> "2016-Crocodile", "2016-Crocodile", "2017-West", "2017-West",
> "2017-Rankin", "2017-Rankin", "2017-Whipray", "2017-Whipray",
> "2017-Crocodile", "2017-Crocodile", "2018-West", "2018-West",
> "2018-Rankin", "2018-Rankin", "2018-Whipray", "2018-Whipray",
> "2018-Crocodile", "2018-Crocodile", "2019-West", "2019-West",
> "2019-Rankin", "2019-Rankin", "2019-Whipray", "2019-Whipray",
> "2019-Crocodile", "2019-Crocodile", "2020-West", "2020-West",
> "2020-Rankin", "2020-Rankin", "2020-Whipray", "2020-Whipray",
> "2020-Crocodile", "2020-Crocodile", "2021-West", "2021-West",
> "2021-Rankin", "2021-Rankin", "2021-Whipray", "2021-Whipray",
> "2021-Crocodile", "2021-Crocodile"), species = c("weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den",
> "weighted_den_carid", "weighted_den", "weighted_den_carid"),
> density = c(0.00109451560281117, 0.484952868327336, 0, 0.086948676470023,
> 0, 0.000175586458772299, 0, 0.0213370469869364, 0.00244750051380243,
> 2.25961874077752, 0, 0, 0, 0.00109652922201019, 0, 0, 0.00155162534766244,
> 1.87765191982742, 0, 0.0506693553371398, 0, 0.00888790576574783,
> 0, 0.000113921166552746, 0.00271835365647371, 1.43239056009749,
> 0, 0.000182039455286541, 0, 0, 0, 0.000561519490035231, 0.00225835591184498,
> 2.40719953239284, 0, 0.000388080206313915, 0, 0.00309583234733728,
> 0, 0.000815020765525142, 9.16873040427497e-05, 0.330946212564868,
> 0, 0.00121708105974097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00120311020545607,
> 0.245785509346677, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0170052902510473, 0.00331914172039662,
> 0.65236339593047, 0.0018818919255523, 0.00514144664157328,
> 0.00049840112185749, 0.00211954056631631, 0, 0.00202007130311886,
> 0.00419876411388295, 0.199634354821455, 0.000976084425739813,
> 0.104217100578605, 0.00017317664770464, 0.00103563821616542,
> 0.000231762069846282, 0.000115118681029652, 0.001688624458484,
> 0.112896098983775, 0.00221388120855345, 0.00851524454018168,
> 0.000145407848151758, 0.000434852081803272, 0, 0.000412676750124396,
> 0.00273638649319108, 0.267608818473059, 0.00332090562164444,
> 0.068723241681447, 0.000426749934946656, 0.00149987725304424,
> 0, 0.000192673737735322, 0.000951619776409427, 0.215338040060959,
> 0.000434586745104274, 0.0478934449975685, 0, 0.00150998374994783,
> 0, 0.00129010186017751, 0.00131030492673741, 0.300718374949211,
> 0.00110524705272365, 0.203148234839554, 0, 0.00205469524493215,
> 0, 0.00279004408491279)), row.names = c(NA, -104L), groups = structure(list(
> Zone = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
> 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Crocodile",
> "Rankin", "West", "Whipray"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2009,
> 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
> 2020, 2021, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,
> 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,
> 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2009, 2010,
> 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020,
> 2021), .rows = structure(list(7:8, 15:16, 23:24, 31:32, 39:40,
> 47:48, 55:56, 63:64, 71:72, 79:80, 87:88, 95:96, 103:104,
> 3:4, 11:12, 19:20, 27:28, 35:36, 43:44, 51:52, 59:60,
> 67:68, 75:76, 83:84, 91:92, 99:100, 1:2, 9:10, 17:18,
> 25:26, 33:34, 41:42, 49:50, 57:58, 65:66, 73:74, 81:82,
> 89:90, 97:98, 5:6, 13:14, 21:22, 29:30, 37:38, 45:46,
> 53:54, 61:62, 69:70, 77:78, 85:86, 93:94, 101:102), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",
> "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = c("tbl_df",
> "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df",
> "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Do you need `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`?

Comment: Actually, geom_bar is working, I just can't get the dam scales adjusted correctly yet. ggplot(df2, aes(x = Zone)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(y = density, color = species, alpha = species, fill = species), position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "C. neb weighted density", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 100, "Caridean weighted density")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.7, 0.7)) + # Color transparency
  facet_wrap(~Year)

Comment: I also had to transform the data to the "long version" (weighted_den_carid and weighted_den are factor levels now under a column header I called "species"). Their respective values are under the col "density".

Comment: I think it would be pretty easy to fix this if you could share your data in `dput` format - the little head of your data frame isn't really enough to demonstrate a solution.

Comment: Trying, I get an error saying it's too much code and not enough "detail".

Comment: Put it outside the code block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your dput, we can create the following code, which appears to do what you asked for, though I'm not sure how effective it is aas a visualization:

```r
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = species, values_from = density) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Zone) - 0.125)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = weighted_den, group = 1, fill = 'weighted_den'),
           width = 0.25) +
  geom_col(aes(x = as.numeric(Zone) + 0.125,
               y = weighted_den_carid / 100,
               fill = 'weighted_den_carid'), width =0.25) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4, labels = levels(df$Zone)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.x * 100,
                                         name = 'weighted_den_carid')) +
  facet_wrap(~Year, scales = 'free_y') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Comment: Ya, its not that useful as a visual, but we were interested in seeing if the density of one species would predict the other (clearly the answer is = not really, haha). Thank you, sir!

Comment: Ah well, it's all good science Nate!

Comment: Quick question! Is there a way to change the order of the x-axis to c('West', 'Rankin', 'Whipray', 'Crocodile')? I tried setting this to a vector and calling it in the aes(), but got this error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (52): level".

Comment: Also tried: scale_x_discrete(limit = c("West", "Rankin", "Whipray", "Crocodile"), labels = c("West", "Rankin", "Whipray", "Crocodile")), but it only changes the labels, not the graphs too.

Comment: @Nate easiest to change the level of the factors ahead of the plot, or, inside the initial ggplot call, do `ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(factor(Zone, levels = c('West', 'Rankin', 'Whipray', 'Crocodile'))) - 0.125))`

Answer (score 1):

First I created a reproducible dataset with random data:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(c(2009, 2010, 2011, 2012), 5),
                  Zone = rep(c("West", "Rankin", "Whipray", "Crocodile"), 5),
                  weighted_den = runif(20, 0, 1),
                  weighted_den_carid = runif(20, 0, 3))
```

After that you should `melt` your data using the following code:

```
library(reshape)
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- melt(df, id = c("Zone", "Year"))
```

And use the following code to plot the bars with second y-axis:

```
df2 %>% ggplot(aes(x = Zone, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous("Carid", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *100, name = "Cneb"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Although, is there a way to keep the "Year" column so I can incorporate this bit of the ggplot code -> "facet_wrap(~Year)"? Also, weighted_den should be about 100x smaller than weighted_den_carid in df2.

Comment: @Nate, I changed the code a bit. Now you can use the Year column too. I created random data so it could be that the weighted_den isn't 100x smaller.